# Getting string index value from Javascript to MVC C# Controller using string[] array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am new in this environment and i just want to ask somebody if it is possible to get the string value not the index value using string[] array as a parameter?

Below are those images: [ajax pass this data into controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf5i2.png)

I am using ajax to pass my data in to the url controller in c# mvc.

By the way, here's my sample array data: [prepared data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jra2z.png).

the highlighted one is my array and in my parameter in mvc # is declared as string [] methodParam: [highlighted parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9iiU.png),

Those not highlighted parameter are working. all i want to do is getting one by one string in methodParam. i tried to use this 
**GetMethodParam.IndexOf("Date").ToString()** but the output is -1 which probably not available in context.

[i just want to get each string and its value because i send it to the email outlook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdkOj.png).

like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rfUs.png).

Any Suggestions, clarification or comments is highly appreciated. Thank you ;) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the individual input in data on ajax call, just use the last one UserHeader
and in Acton(C#) use a model as argument with containing all attributes of UserHeader.

---

Or, remove UserHeader from data and Use each attributes as individual argument in C# Action with same name.

Comment: Thank you Sir Bambam. i will try your suggestion.